# Markov chain: Grasshopper jumps.

Tags: probability, markov-chains

A grasshopper jumps about at random between the corners of a triangle. If
he is at one corner, he is equally likely to jump to either of the other two
corners (but he never jumps straight up in the air and lands on the same
corner where he was before). For each positive integer $t$, find the probability
that, after $t$ jumps, the grasshopper is back on the corner it started from.

---

The state space $S$, is the corners of the triangle, label them $A,B,C$, with the Markov chain having transition matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix}
0&\frac12&\frac12\\
\frac12&0&\frac12\\
\frac12&\frac12&0
\end{pmatrix}.$$
Without loss of generality, suppose the grasshopper starts at corner $A$. Clearly, when $t=1$, we have that it is impossible for the grasshopper to return back to corner $A$, so the probability of which is zero.

Now suppose $t=2$. Well we can either take the path $(BA)$ or $(CA)$, so the probability here is $$2\Big(\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2}\Big)=\frac{1}{2}.$$
Now suppose $t=3$. We can take paths $(BCA)$ or $(CBA)$, so the probability here is $$2\Big(\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2}\Big)=\frac{1}{4}.$$

Comment: To get a fresh look at the problem, instead of writing sequences of which points the grasshopper is at, you could try to write sequences of whether he jumps clockwise or counterclockwise.

Comment: Hmm, I'm a bit confused here. Wouldn't that just essentially give me the same sequences, or would I have a different state space here?

Comment: On the surface, the difference isn't that big. Well, you lose this "no repeats" requirement, which I think makes the combinatorics slightly cleaner, and as you translate between the two views, my sequence will be one letter shorter. But the most important difference is that it drastically changes how you check whether a given sequence of jumps means that the grasshopper is back where he started. It's not about the end points any more, but about counting. Of course, you lose the Markov approach this way.

Comment: Would you like an answer that just diagonalises the transition matrix to get the probability?

Comment: @Arthur I must say I'm still a bit stumped. Looking at the answer that uses the property of transition matrices below, I can safely say that I don't think I would've got to the required answer using combinatorics. However, my interest is piqued now, so could you give me some sample sequences using your clockwise/anti-clockwise sequences for small $t$ values?

Comment: For $t=8$, using 0 to denote a counterclockwise jump and 1 a clockwise jump, some sequences returning to the origin are 11010100 and 00010000. Note that the difference between the number of 0s and the number of 1s is a multiple of 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the "standard" matrix approach to finding the probability. The transition matrix diagonalises as
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
0&\frac12&\frac12\\
\frac12&0&\frac12\\
\frac12&\frac12&0
\end{bmatrix}=PDP^{-1}$$
$$=\begin{bmatrix}
-1&-1&1\\
0&1&1\\
1&0&1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
-\frac12&0&0\\
0&-\frac12&0\\
0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
-\frac13&-\frac13&\frac23\\
-\frac13&\frac23&-\frac13\\
\frac13&\frac13&\frac13
\end{bmatrix}$$
The required answer is the first entry of 
$$A^t\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}=PD^tP^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$$
which turns out to be
$$\frac13+\frac23\left(-\frac12\right)^t$$